# CollectionViewSource in CodeBehind with Template Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, templatebinding

I'm creating a lookless control based on `Selector` in WPF with a Dependency Property named `ListItems`. When `SelectedItems` is changed, I do:

```
// CollectionViewSource ListItems = ...
ListItems.Source = newSelectedItems;
ListItems.Refresh();
```

And in my `ControlTemplate` I bind it to a `ListBox` like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ListItems}"/>
```

But no items appear in my `ListBox`.

I have also tried:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={TemplateBinding ListItems}}"/>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you try ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}", does that still fail?  (Sometimes this works where TemplateBinding does not.)  Do you see any data binding errors in the Output window (e.g. "cannot find property 'ListItems' on 'SomeTotallyUnexpectedType'")?

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion didn't work. I also checked the ouput log and didn't see anything.